# Prove: If $A$ is singular, so is $AB$. Is this correct? Did I assume things that were not appropriate?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, inverse

Prove: If $A$ is singular, so is $AB$.

Contrapositive: If $AB$ is invertible then $A$ is invertible.
If $AB$ is invertible then there exist a matrix $C$ such that $(AB)C=I$.

by associativity, $A(BC)=I$.

right multiplying by a vector $b∈R^n$ we get $A(BCb)=b$.

now we can write $BCb$ as a vector $x∈R^n$ and so

for all $b∈R^n$ the equation $Ax=b$ has a solution.

the above is true IFF

the columns of A span $R^n$

IFF the columns of A are linearly independent

IFF the homogenous system of equations $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution

IFF matrix $A$ is row equivalent to $I$

because $A$ is row equivalent to $I$, $A$ is invertible.

so by contraposition if $A$ is singular, so is $AB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've overthought the problem.  If $AB$ is invertible, then $\exists C (= (AB)^{-1})$ such that $(AB)C=I$.  But then $A(BC)=I$ so $A^{-1}=BC$ and $A$ is invertible.

Taking the contrapositive, if $A$ is singular (i.e., not invertible), then $AB$ can't be invertible (i.e., must be singular).

Comment: but wouldn't I have to show that both A(BC)=I and (BC)A=I to satisfy definition?

Comment: I dont understand how showing A(BC)=I alone implies $A^−1=BC$ because I cant multiply both sides of $A(BC)=I$ by $A^-1$ because that would assume A is invertible

Comment: @bfff There should be eg a theorem in the back of your mind connecting right/left inverses to surjectivity/injectivity and another that says a matrix is surjective iff its injective

Comment: So is proving it the way I proved it considered wrong or a bad practice?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Perhaps not.  I think that's what bfff proved in his original post, so perhaps that was left as an exercise and I was mistaken about overthinking the problem.

Comment: Definitely not wrong.  At most, you reinvented the wheel by essentially reproving the result from which you can get the answer.  But it is true that if a matrix has a right inverse, it also must have a left inverse and once you know they both exist it's very easy to see algebraically that the two must be equal.

Comment: Note that $A$ singular $\Rightarrow AB$ singular is *not* true in general (for the reason given in Calvin Khor's comment). It is true for matrices though.